# How can I edit the array elements?

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables, global

I am new to C Programming. I need to build a project (solving sudoku puzzle with the few data entered by user and WITHOUT THE USE OF POINTER in the program).

The main problem is:
I defined a 2 dimensional global array named sudoku (I used the syntax: extern int sudoku[a][a]). The array is defined in main function after taking input a from user.

Then, I need to access each elements of that array from another function and need to edit the array elements in that funcion.

I got error message like this:

In function \main'
object with variably modified type must have no linkage.
storage size of 'sudoku' isn't constant.

How can I solve this ? please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Your question is unclear.  Show ALL relevant code and the exact errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int sudoku[10][10];
main()
{
int i,j,n;
clrscr();
printf("enter the array size\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("enter the values into an array\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
scanf("%d",&sudoku[i][j]);
}
}
arr(sudoku,n);
getch();
}
void arr(int sudoku[10[10],int n)
{
printf("array content are as follows\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
printf("%d",sudoku[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
}
```